# Adding the "Interesting" tab to the Questions Page

Tags: feature-request, interesting-page, questions-page

Clicking on the SO site logo in the top-left corner or browsing direct to [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) navigates one to a page of questions that includes the ["Interesting" questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) - that is, a group of questions tagged with your self-selected favourite tags.

That tab is absent from the main [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) page - that is, the page accessed by [clicking the "Questions" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions).

**Proposal: Let's add this tab to the Questions page.**

It seems counter-intuitive to me for it to be hidden away with no explicit link to find it (that I've found, anyway). I've read discussion elsewhere on meta as to whether the "Interesting" tab should be a tab at all, but given that it is, doesn't a link to it naturally belong on the Questions page?

**Edit: Added 50 point bounty to attract a little attention.**

**Edit: Here's what it would look like...**

[image]

Comment: Related question here: [How I can switch to Interesting and hot tabs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122751/137484)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I agree that it would be nice to have on the Questions page, it isn't terribly hard to find (I found it fairly quickly). Now, this does not mean that it is 100% intuitive, but I don't think it needs to be. (what was the quote, ["the only 100% intuitive interface is the human nipple"](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2002/08/nipple.html) (when I had kids I learned that this is not, in fact correct (kids need to learn how to nurse). There is no completely intuitive interface (and I feel cheated)))

My biggest concern would be the fact that there is so little real estate on the questions page at the moment anyway. Adding another item might make it necessarily cluttered.

On the other hand, I actually was about to make your comment on the blog entry that Mr. Atwood originally announced the, "we're going to show interesting stuff on the homepage" feature, but then I realized that the large icon on the left manages to do that for me.

Comment: +1 for the point about screen estate being limited. And also for ensuring that this question will turn up anytime someone searches for "nipple".

Comment: @razlebe Literally an LOL

Comment: I've added a screen grab to the question. It doesn't look like screen estate is *too* much of an issue, though the tab bar undoubtedly looks busier. Any thouhgts?

Comment: I think it IS hard to find.  I've had to go through pages of `meta` results to find this question, just to condfirm that the "Interesting Tab` wasn't obliterated… and now I need to reread your answer to figure out how to actually get to it… _That' aint right._

Answer (score 2):

No, I think this won't be a good idea.

All tabs under https://stackoverflow.com/questions show **full list of questions**, with paging.

The [Interesting tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) exist only on very few sites in Stack Exchange, and showing list of **only 90 questions**, picked by a complicated algorithm according to various parameters.

Those are two different things, having both in the same page as tabs is wrong in my opinion.

Comment: "Featured" shows only questions which are featured (obviously) rather than a full list, no? Though was unaware that "Interesting" is unique to SO.

Comment: @razlebe the "featured"  tab under /questions show all featured (i.e. with an active bounty) questions (with paging, right now >300) while the "featured" tab in the homepage shows only 90 or so, with "Looking for more featured questions? Browse the complete list" in the bottom. Different, though this one might be a bug or oversight.

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally approving this idea... I like it on SO how I can skip directly to the good questions. But since they are less questions here then on SO shouldn't we put your favorite tags + related tags?

Comment: Thanks Senick. I'm not proposing any change here to the existing "Interesting Tags" tab in terms of it's content, just proposing adding it to the Questions page. I'll leave it to you to suggest changing the content in a separate feature-request if you wish. :)

Comment: Meh... we will have to see if this feature pass the test first anyway!