# How I can switch to Interesting and hot tabs?

Tags: support, hot-questions, interesting-page

Yesterday I was working with StackOverflow and suddenly I noticed I have some tabs on my page that I've never seen before ("interesting","hot" ,...) but when I hit the questions link to see newest questions it switched back to normal ("newest","unanswered",...) and I can't realize how to switch to those tabs again. Would you please help me ?

Comment: Related feature request here: [Adding the "Interesting" tab to the Questions Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87470/137484)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just click on the Stack Overflow logo.

[Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions):

---

[image]

---

[Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com):

---

[image]

---

Comment: ...and then go and upvote this [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87470/adding-the-interesting-tab-to-the-questions-page) if like me you find this to be unintuitive UI design.