# Please use proper HTML/CSS to size ads on right margin

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Okay, maybe this is a minor nit and doesn't affect anybody else, but I end up on the Careers page at least 10 times a day because the image expands and resizes after the page has started loading. If you never show ads there that are of a different size, can we please fix the dimensions of those ads so that the HTML doesn't adjust *vertically* as the images render?

When I'm navigating around Stack Overflow I click on the "Questions" tab in the main nav. Then I click on my "favorite tag" link on the right. When the page first loads, this tag is near the top, but if I don't click fast enough, the careers ad (usually, or some other ad in some cases) expands and loads into its place, and that's where my click goes. It is not a deal-breaker but it is frustrating.

I'm going to label this as a bug though it is probably by design that the content could support any height of ad. In the short term if all the ads are the same size I think `<div id="hireme">` could have a hard-coded height so that the content doesn't jump around to accommodate the image(s) as they load in.

To show the actual symptom for those who can't reproduce it, here is how the questions page looks when I initially load it:

[image]

Sometimes I try to click that [tag:sql-server*] under "Favorite Tags" too quickly. By the time my click registers, here is what the actual sidebar looks like:

[image]

Is there any way (since it sounds like we can't assign dimensions to these ads) that the Favorite Tags div could be moved above the ad? I understand the goal of advertising but I also understand how inadvertent clicks contributing to an inflated click-through count is not helpful either.

The workaround of course is to be more patient and wait for the page to fully render.

Comment: B-b-b-b-browser?

Comment: Sorry, this happens in Firefox, but I'm sure the HTML resizes the same way in other browsers as well (I just don't use them very frequently). I just reproduced it in Safari as well.

Comment: "If you never show ads there that are of a different size"....but we do, so that's not an immediate option.

Comment: You must have a slow connection to the ad server, mine resizes almost instantaneously (and I'm behind a corporate firewall).

Comment: @NickCraver can't the dimensions of the ad be part of the metadata that comes along with the ad choice, and hence part of the rendering?

Comment: Hm...  I've never had this problem in any browser, and I have pretty slow internet.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I don't think my Internet connection is slow. http://www.speedtest.net/result/1923970892.png

Comment: @AaronBertrand - no they cannot, that choice isn't made by the server that renders the page, it's made by adzerk.

Comment: So @minitech when you go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions the ads on the right side don't move at all, the images are clearly visible the moment the page loads, and you don't see any visual shifting of the content whatsoever?

Comment: @NickCraver I'd even be amenable to making it a fixed height equal to the height of the largest ad you support (I'm sure the domain of ad sizes is known), knowing that will mean some white space in some cases.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I don't see that as acceptable, we can't just throw away hundreds of pixels in the sidebar on *most* pages.  It's not "some" cases, it'd be all cases, since one of the ads is smaller *most* of the time.  So far, no one else has reported this issue (that I'm aware of), and that's out of tens of millions of users.

Comment: @NickCraver ok, so what about the suggestion to move the "Favorite Tags" section above the ad? Or reports of sidebar layout issues in general? Has there been any general feature request for letting users dictate how their sidebar is laid out, that maybe didn't cite this specific symptom as one of the reasons?

Comment: @NickCarver I refreshed the page about 100 times (sorry for the extra traffic). The range of combined ad heights went from ~530px to the max at 573px. So if you fixed the div height at 573px, the most you'd ever lose is 43px (worst case scenario, not "hundreds") and in my sample size it was much more frequently less than that or 0, since it seemed very few ads combined to fall into the 530-540px range.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: No horizontal shifting. There's vertical shifting of the content below it, of course, but the ads have loaded by the time I get down there (and I don't use the sidebar much either). Is that really a problem?

Comment: @minitech Yes, I was only talking about vertical shifting. For me, it's not a problem, just an annoyance, as I mentioned above. What happens is several times a day when I'm intending to go to my favorite tags page I end up on the careers site in a new window. If I was job-hunting right now, that'd be great, but I'm not.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I think you're thinking of this the wrong way entirely.  The comments here focus on solving the **symptoms**, which to be honest I'm not really concerned with...that's a consolation prize.  How about we try and address the core *issue* first?  Why are the ads loading so slowly for you?

Comment: I'm not sure about the speed. This is the only place where I'm observing any such symptoms, and as I posted above in one of the comments, I've got a pretty fast pipe here. I think no matter how fast those ads load, if anything below them loads first, that content is going to shift. And with content coming from someone else's servers, I think that is inevitable. I used to be in the ad business and we fought this kind of problem all the time.

Comment: I've run into this consistently as well.  I just started going to my favorite tags pages from the "Interesting" tab (since the favorite tags are on top, there is no vertical jump to worry about).  I don't find the "Questions" tab all that useful (unfiltered) anyway on SO =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 yes that's true, though occasionally in doing so I spot a question I can answer that falls outside of the tags I typically monitor. Ah yes, the "Interesting" tab has exactly the layout I like - favorite tags *above* the ads. Perfect, thanks.

Comment: It's on the main page (http://stackoverflow.com/), the leftmost tab.  And that's a good point, I have snagged a question I could answer like that a couple times.

Comment: I guess I never come in to the main page, and I had a heck of a time finding that tab from any other interface. Why isn't that a tab if I go to Questions?

Comment: Hmmm, there *is* a [feature request for that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87470/adding-the-interesting-tab-to-the-questions-page), although it hasn't gotten a ton of attention.

Comment: @NickCraver I'm reporting the same problem

Comment: Just a short question...why not create a bookmark? Would save you one click at least.

Comment: I do use bookmarks (see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138371/favorite-tags-appear-below-advertisements-and-not-easily-visible/138373#comment389061_138373)). But I still find myself looking for the nav on the right. Anyway if I'm supposed to see the ads, forcing me to create bookmarks specifically so I no longer need to click anywhere near the ads...

Comment: You might want to consider using AdBlock. I use it because the adverts, although very fast, load so much slower compared to the rest of the page.

Comment: @thirtydot I agree that blocking the ads altogether is a workaround, but I don't think it's the one that will get any official endorsement from the network. :-) I am not opposed to seeing the ads, and I don't even care if they take a long time to load. But their speed should not impact the layout of the page or hamper my experience in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this issue up. While I totally respect that this is an annoying aspect of our sites, it is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). This is because **adzerk** serves our ads for us, and they control the height etc. To be fair, at the time of writing this, the load is so bloody quick that I doubt you're able to reliably click the favourites link before the ad loads. Still, I understand your issue.

The short version is: we're not going to change it anytime soon. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: I begrudgingly accept this; thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

I'm glad I'm not the only one to suffer from this (two in distress make sorrow less); I've almost clicked accidentally all of the Stack Exchange Ads for this sneaky behavior.

It would be cool to fix this, but I'm aware it's certainly caused by a slow connection to the *adzerk* server from my side (I'm from Italy).

[image]

Comment: pretty sure adzerk is on Amazon EC2

Comment: @JeffAtwood Yep, it's on Amazon S3.