# Favorite tags appear below Advertisements and not easily visible

Tags: feature-request

**Suggestion:**

The **Favorite Tags** appear below the Advertisements and are not easily visible. They should appear somewhere on top for fast navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I complained about this a few months ago, from a slightly different angle. I just want the size of the ads to remain fixed, since even on a fast connection I often pop through to the careers page because I click as the content is loading and re-sizing:

[Please use proper HTML/CSS to size ads on right margin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130804/please-use-proper-html-css-to-size-ads-on-right-margin)

But I do agree, it would be nice to be able to put your favorite tag buttons above the ads. It already works this way on the [home page](https://stackoverflow.com/), why not on the [questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) too?

To be honest, I've just added bookmarks for the search results for my most favorite tags, and navigate via the bookmarks on my toolbar instead of using the inconsistent right-hand navigation.

Comment: I also suggest them to define a certain area for advertisement rather than Ads blocking what is important.

Comment: I guess the basic idea is that we *should* see the ads. :-) But it would be nice to have the buttons in a fixed location, so they don't move away exactly when you click them.

Comment: @BoPersson sure, I get that they want us to see the ads, but if my workaround for the current bad/inconsistent behavior is to create my own buttons nowhere near the ads, what they've actually accomplished is that I don't see the ads at all. Even unintentionally fooling me into clicking an ad when that wasn't my intention is not the honest way to build up clickstream revenue. :-)