# Place "Favorite Tags" above the ad instead of below it, at least after privilege gain of "reduce ads"

Tags: feature-request, advertising

It would be great to show the "Favorite Tags" above the ad in the right side of the window instead of below it when showing a list of questions screens

[image]

Because, the "Favorite Tags" are something we use to switch between different set of question lists as we are interested specifically in some areas only.

It is a tedious task to scroll each time we need to click the next tag once we didn't find any new question in the current tag. It will be great help for regular users.

Instead if the "Favorite Tags" are on top, we can have quick click on each tags and have a quick check of each tag updates and move on.

Comment: We actually do reduce ads in one of the privilege things. I think it's unlisted though, and it's for the leaderboard ads, not the "in house" sidebar ads, I believe

Comment: reduced ad does take effect currently for removal of leader board ads. But, it was a suggestion to improve the usability for a regular user by moving the sidebar ads bit lower at least below the "Favorite Tags" list. It will make the question listings toggling by clicking on favorite tags more user friendly without a scroll each time

Comment: @RinoTom The whole point of ads is to place them where people will notice them, and not in places where they will be ignored.  This is a problem that goes away very quickly for even a moderately active user when you hit the limited ads permissions, so just wait until then.

Comment: Use adblock, like most other folks :)

Comment: @LoremIpsum ya that is a good client side option. :)

Comment: @Servy there is option to show the ads at normal area for a non-user and an early user. I am asking this as an improvement along with the privilege gain of "reduce ads". What is this "limited ads" permissions in your comment? I think you are talking about "reduce ads" only.

Comment: Yes please! A *huge* pet peeve of mine is sometimes the ads don't load right away, and unloaded ads don't reserve their space in the UI, so there have been times when I go to click on my Favorite Tag and right as I do the ad loads in that space so I end up clicking the ad instead.

Comment: @RinoTom The purpose of ads is for them to be noticed and clicked.  If they're only placed in locations where nobody ever sees or clicks on them then SE loses a significant portion of it's income, most of which (I would imagine) comes from anonymous and low-rep users.  The design of the business model is that they are somewhat more disruptive for those users so that the active regular users don't need to experience them.  I happen to very much enjoy that model.

Comment: @Rachel, same here :)

Comment: @Servy In regards to `"This is a problem that goes away very quickly for even a moderately active user when you hit the limited ads permissions"`, no it doesn't. I have over 30K rep on SO and the same large ad still shows above my Favorite Tags section, and I'm always having to scroll down to click on my Favorite Tags. Also note my [previous comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168461/place-favorite-tags-above-the-ad-instead-of-below-it#comment496415_168461) for an additional reason why I fully support this feature request

Comment: @Servy, I do agree that ads needs visibility. But, this suggestion is only for question listing pages. Other pages, the ads can go on as of now. Those will get a good visibility as well. I feel usability should not be ruined for advertising. That is why I suggested this. What Rachel commented above is also a reason for this suggestion. If SE will loose a lot by this. Okay, I'm just shrugging it off.

Comment: @Rachel The favorite tags are above the ads for me.  Are you sure you aren't thinking of recent tags, because that's the only info I see below favorited tags.

Comment: @RinoTom I don't see how  usability is "ruined" because of this.  It's a minor annoyance that's easily avoided.

Comment: @Servy I just double checked, and the Favorite Tags are above the ad on the home page, but below the ad on the Questions page. So I guess you are correct for part of it :) I don't normally look at the home page often since the first thing I do when coming to the site is click on the Questions or Unanswered links to look at the new questions. I would really love it if the Favorite Tags on the Unanswered question page was above the Related lists though, and if they filtered correctly for "Unanswered" questions when clicked on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please use proper HTML/CSS to size ads on right margin](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130804/please-use-proper-html-css-to-size-ads-on-right-margin)

Comment: @BoPersson, the question you suggested is talking about the rendering of HTML/CSS for ads. That is also a concern behind this question. But, the main suggestion is to move "Favorite Tags" above side bar ad space  to reduce the effect of this issue. And that change will even improve the usability by reducing some scroll in question listing page which is a regularly visited page.