# Interesting tab on StackOverflow

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tabs

One day I directed to SO and was met with the awesome `Interesting` page, which I really like. But when I travel away from it, I have to re-enter the query string to get it back. Is there a plan to make this tab visible so I can click to it anytime?

Comment: *Is there a plan to make this tab visible so I can click to it anytime?* Here's a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87470/1486720) it isn't marked as tag [meta-tag:status-declined] for it, so we don't really know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can click on the Stack Overflow logo and it'll show the interesting page.

[image: Interesting Tab]

Comment: That's awesome. Wish I knew that before. But I still wish it were a tab so it were more readily visible. To newcomers, I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the homepage: https://stackoverflow.com/ rather than the questions tab: https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Comment: @Habib No, he's entering: `http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting`  No query string is required to go to the homepage.

Comment: My bad. I read it wrong,